# golang get char* as return value from dll

Tags: go, unsafe-pointers

I'm using golang to call a Dll function like `char* fn()`, the dll is not written by myself and I cannot change it. Here's my code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "syscall"
    "unsafe"
)

func main() {
    dll := syscall.MustLoadDLL("my.dll")
    fn := dll.MustFindProc("fn")

    r, _, _ := fn.Call()

    p := (*byte)(unsafe.Pointer(r))
    // define a slice to fill with the p string
    data := make([]byte, 0)

    // loop until find '\0'
    for *p != 0 {
        data = append(data, *p)        // append 1 byte
        r += unsafe.Sizeof(byte(0))    // move r to next byte
        p = (*byte)(unsafe.Pointer(r)) // get the byte value
    }
    name := string(data) // convert to Golang string
    fmt.Println(name)
}
```

I have some questions:

1. Is there any better way of doing this? There're hundred of dll functions like this, I'll have to write the loop for all functions.
2. For very-long-string like 100k+ bytes, will `append()` cause performance issue?
3. **Solved**. the `unsafe.Pointer(r)` causes linter *govet* shows warning `possible misuse of unsafe.Pointer`, but the code runs fine, how to avoid this warning? **Solution:** This can be solved by adding `-unsafeptr=false` to `govet` command line, for *vim-ale*, add `let g:ale_go_govet_options = '-unsafeptr=false'`.

[image]

Comment: Why not just use `C.GoString`?

Comment: Consider adding your solution as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Casting uintptr as upointer is haram.
You must read the rules:
https://golang.org/pkg/unsafe/#Pointer

But there's hacky way, that shouldn't produce warning:

```golang
//go:linkname gostringn     runtime.gostringn
func gostringn(p uintptr, l int) string

//go:linkname findnull     runtime.findnull
//go:nosplit
func findnull(s uintptr) int

// ....

name := gostringn(r, findnull(r))
```

Functions takes pointer, but we link them from runtime as uintptr because they have same sizeof.

Might work in theory. But is also frowned upon.

Getting back to your code, as JimB said, you could do it one line with:

```golang
name := C.GoString((*C.char)(unsafe.Pointer(r)))
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the following solution by tracking the `os.Args` of the go source code, But I am based on go1.17. If you are in another version, you can read the source code to solve it.

```golang
func UintPtrToString(r uintptr) string {
    p := (*uint16)(unsafe.Pointer(r))
    if p == nil {
        return ""
    }

    n, end, add := 0, unsafe.Pointer(p), unsafe.Sizeof(*p)
    for *(*uint16)(end) != 0 {
        end = unsafe.Add(end, add)
        n++
    }
    return string(utf16.Decode(unsafe.Slice(p, n)))
}
```